# How to get the full url from a link

Tags: python, html, url

Say that I go to `http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/index.html` and there are the following links:

`<a href="/about/">Link</a>`
`<a href="/about">Link</a>`
`<a href="/page.html/">Link</a>`
`<a href="/page.html">Link</a>`

The problem I have is that I cannot tell when I should concatenate what parts together as some have slashes, some do not, and I have to take into consideration that

`http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/index.html/about/`

should really be

`http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/about/`.

Also, how can I tell that `/about` is a directory not a file?
I am using `python3.5` with the `urllib.request` module.

Comment: rest is ok, but how you are going to decide that `dir1` comes before `dir2` in the url?

Comment: Do you mean how do I know to go to `http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2` or what order to put it in?

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: Yes what is the funda which is going to decide `dir1`comes before `dir2`

Comment: I am not sure which is my problem because the order is very important

Comment: I don't know python, but wont `../` work ? eg: `<a href="../about/">Link</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this-

```
base_url = "http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2"
next = "/index.html"
```

then, for each link, extract the `href` attribute and assign it to the `next`. Your final url for each link will be `base_url + next`.